# admob pay us for showing the ads , or for ads which is clicked on inside our application?

Tags: admob

I want to add admob to my application to earn money when showing the ads in my application
  I want to know , the payment I should get for the showing the ads or if the users clicked on the ads ?

which of them I got paid for , and is there any setting I should adjust to enable both of them ?

ie. is admob pay us as CPC  (cost per click) or CPM (cost per thousand impressions)

Answer (score 0):

Admob is cost per click, as are most reputable ad networks.

Comment: so what they mean by the following "Advertisers running CPM ads set their desired price per 1000 ads served and pay each time their ad appears.
As a publisher, you'll earn revenue each time a CPM ad is served to your app and viewed by a user. CPM ads compete against cost-per-click (CPC) ads in our ad auction. We'll display whichever ad is expected to earn more revenue for you." which is found on their site ?